# How do I store Firestore data in a variable that I can manipulate in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firefox

Let's say I have a variable for integers called currentShells

```
        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

                let data = document.data()

                currentShells = data!["Shells"]! as! Int
            }
        }
        print(currentShells)
```

When I print out the variable, I am unable to. Swift is forcing me to add "self.currentShells" in front of the query but it does not update the variable as a result. How do I query data from my Firestore database and use it in swift?

EDIT: For more context, I want to take the current value in currentShells (which I want to query from my Firestore) and add a fixed integer to that amount and update it into my database

Comment: getDocument is asychronous and will complete some time in the future.  Use `currentShells` only inside the callback or you are certain that it's already completed.

Comment: I added an edit to my question, do you have any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: To add a bit more info; Firebase data is only valid within the closure following the Firebase call. Code is faster than the internet and it takes times for data to return from the server. In this case, the print(currentShells) code will execute way before that data returns. So, work with Firebase data within the closure following the call. If you need data outside the closure, you can use an @escapting completion handler to pass it back to a calling function.

Answer (score 2):

As Doug Stevenson said, *getDocument* is executed asynchronously. That means

```
print(currentShells)
```

can (and mostly will) be executed before

```
currentShells = data...
```

is. 
Changing your code to

```
docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
   if let document = document, document.exists {
      let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
      print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

      let data = document.data()

      currentShells = data!["Shells"]! as! Int
      print("after update: \(currentShells)")
   }
}
print("probably before update: \(currentShells)")
```

should print your updated data.

---

**Advice**
If you aren’t 100% sure that an optional is set and of a certain type, you should not use implicit unwrapping. This can easily lead to crashes!
It is safer to use `guard` or `if let`:

```
if let data = data, let shells = data["Shells"] as? Int {
    currentShells = shells
}
```

---

**Edit**
To execute other functions with new value of currentShells:
- if you need to execute same function every time currentShells is updated, update your var:

```
var currentShells: Int {
   didSet {
      yourFunc(currentShells)
   }
}
```

- otherwise, pass a completion block when calling the function to update currentShells:

```
func getShells(completion: @escaping ((Int) -> ())) {
   ...
   docRef.getDocument { ...
      if let document ... {
         ...
         currentShells = ...
         completion(currentShells)
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Mefew did this help you?

Comment: This helped but I am still stuck on how to use the variable currentShells to run a function that happens after this. Basically,  is there a way to find out when the getDocument asynchronous command is done so I can execute another function?